# Need help! Messed with my VM IPv4 :/

Tags: google-app-engine, ip, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, vps

I'm a noob, I know.
I made a very stupid mess with my Gcloud Windows 2008 VM IP settings. In order to debbug a software that wasn't getting to use the Internet properly, I changed it's IPv4 settings from "obtain an IP automatically" to use the following: "206.214.211.165". Result = I totally f#ed up my VM internet connection, making not possible to even connect to it.
Is it fixable? I could just create a new instance, but I don't want to lose my data :(

Anyone?

Comment: this is offtopic, but just give the other network party (i imagine the host) an IP and netmask so it is in the same network, and then you can access the VM through its static IP.

Comment: thanks for being helpful. i actually tried that, but it didn't work or maybe did not do it correctly, mind elaborating please?

Comment: or just go to cloud console and assign new ip. no need to connect to vm for that.

Comment: i did it multiple times, but it seems that doing it doesn't change the settings I made inside windows

Comment: anyone got an idea? :/

Answer (score 1):

Although this is offtopic, you could try the following:

- Shutdown your current VM (do not delete your disks!)
- Create a new VM
- Attach the disk of your old VM to the new VM

  - Option a) Save of your data what you can and use the new VM
  - Option b) Fix your old VM from the new VM (which is hardcore!) and restart your old VM. I believe the IP configuration is registry based so you'll have to search the web for something like "change IP in registry rescue boot"